# how to simulate timeout in mitmproxy addon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mitmproxy

[mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) is a library in Python (python-3.x) to monitor, manipulate, and debug HTTP protocol. It encapsulates an HTTP request into a Flow object and allows to manipulate them via addons.

I wanna stop a flow if it matches a condition. So the client will wait for a time and get a timeout response.

It does not matter in which event it must be handled.

Comment: flow.kill is a method to destroy the flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow object consists of utilities to do so. Jus kill and set error message as follow:

```
        flow.kill()
        flow.client_conn.error = "Connection killed by an addon."
```